# How to add a leading zero in a ASP.NET Core route rule?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

An ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC app has the following rule:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "blog_list_year_month",
    defaults: new { 
        controller = "Blog", 
        action = "Index", 
        year = (int?)null, 
        month = (int?)null
    },
    template: "blog/{year?}/{month?}");
```

For January 2018, the rule generates an url like `blog/2018/1`.

How to express that the month should be always two digits long? I.e. the engine will rather generate an url `blog/2018/01`?

Comment: (upvoted good question) But... Why does it matter?

Comment: (unordered reasoning) 1) Personal preferences/tastes. 2) The urls are intentionally inspired by Wordpress (WP uses two digits). 3) Generally, I prefer months in a two digit form if used as identifiers. 4) Its better for ordering.

Comment: Those answer are great for future readers :D

Comment: If this is an anonymous type, could you just make `year` and `month` strings, and format them as you like?

Comment: What you mean by the anonymous type? The associated controller's method is `public async Task<ViewResult> Index(int? year = null, int? month = null, int? pageNumber = null)`. I am not a fan of doing type checks and type conversions inside this method body unless really necessary.

Comment: @alik I don't think you need to change your controller's method. Just try changing the `year` and `month` lines so that they are strings instead, and then make sure you use `ToString()` to format those strings.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Where to put the `ToString()` call in the route definition?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at regular expressions for two digit months and setting that as a constraint on the route?

For example:

```
new {month = @"(0[1-9]|1[0-2])"}
```

That should constrain your parameter down to two digits.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like the way to do it.  I looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1 which has detailed examples of route templates, and the only one that even comes close is the regex one.

Comment: If I put this constraint, the route is skipped when searching for a right route while generating a link as the generated urls have these values as query parameters `/Blog/BlogPost/?year=2018&month=1` (tried in another rule).

Comment: @alik I think your two options would be to either a) change the way url's are formatted, padding them with a zero or b) adding an or statement onto the regular expression to allow one character routes....but then that defeats the purpose of the route constraint to begin with :(

Comment: I just got an idea for another workaround which I currently tend to. Duplicate the route, one for 1-9 (with an initial zero in the template), second for 10-12 (without the zero). However, I am usually unable to fall in love with these kind of hacks. I still naively hope there is an elegant solution :)